# jQuery/Ajax to dynamically load a specific id PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm relatively new to jQuery/Ajax and I was wondering what would be the best way of loading via jQuery/AJAX a php page with an ID attached to it.

obviously

```
<?php $id = $_SESSION[id]; ?>
<script>
var pageUrl = new Array(); 
pageUrl[1] = "tab1.html?id=<php echo $id;?>"; 
.....
</script>
```

makes no sense.

What would be the best way of going about this? Thank you!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ jQuery docs are very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `$.get` command and send parameters with it.

```
$.get("tab1.html", { id: <?php echo $id; ?> },
  function(data){
    alert("Output goes into the variable data: " + data);
  });
```

Comment: Can't believe it was so simple. Thank you!